# Ingesting raster dataset to Google Earth Engine using manifest.json

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap, google-cloud, google-colab

I am preparing a pipeline to injest raster dataset (GRACE-FO data) to the Google Earth Engine (GEE) platform. The dataset are already uploaded to google cloud storage bucket (gs://gee-ingest-); and I am using **google colab** to perform the ingestion task using command:

```
!earthengine set_project gee-ait
!earthengine upload image --manifest /content/json/20020405_20020501.json
```

Here is a sample of my *20020405_20020501.json*, manifest file(unsure if everything is right):

```
{
"name": "projects/ee-User-Test/assets/GRACE/MASS_GRIDS/LAND/20020405_20020501",
"tilesets": [
    {
        "id": "20020405_20020501",
        "sources": [
            {
                "uris": [
                    "gs://gee-ingest-<USER>/grace/lwe_thickness_layer-102.tif"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"bands": [
    {
        "id": "lwe_thickness_csr",
        "tileset_id": "20020405_20020501"
    }
],
"properties": {
    "scale_factor": 10000
}}
```

After running the above `earthengine upload` command, the following message is displayed:

```
Successfully saved project id
W0215 02:33:27.848309 136056259874816 _default.py:683] No project ID could be determined. Consider running `gcloud config set project` or setting the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable
Started upload task with ID: EXKL3DUUWNKMZZSTJUKIHONF
```

However, the dataset is not being ingested. Can anyone provide me any inputs if this is the correct approach? I am ready to implement alternative solution, as long as it includes `manifest.json` approach as the requirement is to automate the ingestion workflow.

Comment: Double check your bucket name -- is it just "gee-ingest-" ?  in your manifest file you have "gee-ingest-<USER>" which seems incorrect

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I've replaced that.

Comment: I see that you did `set_project`, which should be fine.. but in your case I would also try `--project gee-ait` in the second ``earthengine` command -- it's worth a shot  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#set_a_cloud_project